# Apache Camel Swagger - using JPA entity as rest type

Tags: jpa, apache-camel, swagger, swagger-ui

i have this Rest-DSL:

```
// this api creates new user
rest("/user")
    .post()
    .type(User.class).to("jpa://com.project.User")
```

This is my entities:

```
public class User{
    @Id
    private String id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_role")
    private Role role;
}

public class Role{
    @Id
    private String id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    private List<User> users;
}
```

my problem is in my swagger in the Body value parameter example. It contains like this:

```
{
  "id": "string",
  "role": {
    "id": "string",
    "users": [
      {
        "id": "string",
        "roles": [
          {}
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

quite complicated, although i need only `id` and `id_role` parameters to create (POST) new user. I hope the body example shows like this:

```
{
  "id": "string",
  "id_role": "string" 
}
```

Comment: You likely need to add swagger annotations to your model classes, as its likely do not understand JPA annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that my entities are not created properly. These was i learned:

1. [Configure CascadeType in associated JPA entities](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/)

   ```
   @Entity

   public class User {
       @Id
       private String id;
       @ManyToOne
       @JoinColumn(name = "id_role")
       private Role role;
   }

   @Entity
   public class Role{
       @Id
       private String id;
       @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
       private List<User> users;
   }
   ```
2. to make class not recursive, set @JsonIgnore

   ```
   @Entity
   @JsonIdentityInfo(
         generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
         property = "id")
   public class User{
       @Id
       private String id;
       @ManyToOne
       @JoinColumn(name = "id_role")
       private Role role;
   }

   @Entity
   @JsonIdentityInfo(
         generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
         property = "id")
   public class Role{
       @Id
       private String id;
       @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
       @JsonIgnore
       // this attribute will not appear inside Role class
       private List<User> users;
   }
   ```